# How to use Outer Apply in oracle while converting from SQL Server

Tags: sql, oracle, outer-apply

I am trying to convert a code which is written in SQL to oracle and it is using outer apply in it. But for some reason the outer apply is not working in oracle. I am using oracle 12c. The code which i am converting is:

```
select * from FROM table1 S1
OUTER APPLY (VALUES (S1.FM46B_PROV_NET_SPEC_P, '1'),
                    (S1.PROV_NET_SPEC_1,'2'),
                    (S1.PROV_NET_SPEC_2,'3'),
                    (S1.PROV_NET_SPEC_3,'4')) PS(PROV_SPEC, SpecType)
```

I did write the code in oracle using left join and union but it is not working. Could someone please advise me on what needs to be done in-order to write the code using outer apply or using some other way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use `select from dual`:

```
select * 
from table1 S1 outer apply
     (select S1.FM46B_PROV_NET_SPEC_P as prev_spec, '1' as spectype from dual union all
      select S1.PROV_NET_SPEC_1, '2' from dual union all
      select S1.PROV_NET_SPEC_2, '3' from dual union all
      select S1.PROV_NET_SPEC_3, '4' from dual
     ) PS;
```

I would use the equivalent `cross join lateral` instead of `outer apply` to be explicit about the type of join, but both are supported.

In any case, Oracle provided support for lateral joins, but did not provide support for the derived tables using `values`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to `UNPIVOT` the columns to rows then:

```sql
select *
FROM   table1
UNPIVOT (
  prov_spec FOR spec_type IN (
    FM46B_PROV_NET_SPEC_P AS '1',
    PROV_NET_SPEC_1 AS '2',
    PROV_NET_SPEC_2 AS '3',
    PROV_NET_SPEC_3 AS '4' 
  )
);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 ( id, FM46B_PROV_NET_SPEC_P, PROV_NET_SPEC_1, PROV_NET_SPEC_2, PROV_NET_SPEC_3 ) AS
SELECT 1, '1.spec.p', '1.spec.1', '1.spec.2', '1.spec.3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '2.spec.p', '2.spec.1', '2.spec.2', '2.spec.3' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> ID | SPEC_TYPE | PROV_SPEC
> -: | :-------- | :--------
>  1 | 1         | 1.spec.p 
>  1 | 2         | 1.spec.1 
>  1 | 3         | 1.spec.2 
>  1 | 4         | 1.spec.3 
>  2 | 1         | 2.spec.p 
>  2 | 2         | 2.spec.1 
>  2 | 3         | 2.spec.2 
>  2 | 4         | 2.spec.3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3b32aae212ad0eb656ff82a4a47e544c)*

Comment: Hello MT0. The solution that i wanted was more like similar to outer apply and the answer from Gordon actually helped. Anyways, thank you for your time :)

Comment: @MT0 . . . You do know that `unpivot` is not equivalent to a lateral join in this case because unpivot filters out `NULL` values.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Then use the `INCLUDE NULLS` clause to include them.